# Are these Holly tree leaves affected by White Mildew?

Tags: identification, trees, mildew

I just noticed that one of my Holly trees has some leaves with white tips like these:

[image]

It doesn't quite match pictures I've seen of White Mildew online, but I've never noticed this before so wanted to determine if this was anything serious.  My other Holly bushes and trees seem to be fine.  Could it be pest or heat related damage instead?  For perspective, I live in Middle Tennessee, which has pretty hot summers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not mildew these are sections of the leaf that have died back due to insufficient water or heat stress or both.  To determine if it is pest damage we would need to see what's going on under the leaves.

Just detach the leaves that are damaged and water before the cooler times in autumn and winter

Comment: Thanks, that makes me feel better.  I actually have been watering it a few times per week regularly throughout the summer, but even still, the sun has been baking our plants in the heat.  I'll remove the bad leafs and keep an eye out to make sure it doesn't get worse.

Comment: It is frequent to see such damages on holly trees (Ilex aquifolium), also on wild ones.